# Why do I not get a response from JSON post request unless the number of rows is limited?

Tags: mysql, json

I am using a JSON post request to return rows from a mySQL database.  My server-side language is php and unless I limit the results in sql to about 45 I don't get a response.  No errors just no response.  Any advice would be appreciated.
The serverside code is as follows;

```
    <?php
  include('../config.php');
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $itemGrp = $_POST['itemGrp'];
  $jobs_sql = "SELECT custName
                    ,SODocNum
                    ,itemName
                    ,cast(thickness as decimal (4,2)) as 'thickness'
                    ,case when ca_Description like 'Diary%' then ca_Description else 'Bespoke Diary' end as ca_Description
                    ,Quantity
                    ,version_id
                    ,case when T0.rqdByDate is null then '' else T0.rqdByDate end as rqdByDate
                    ,T0.despatchDate
                    ,case when T0.versionStatus = 010 then '' else 'w3-disabled' end as 'disableCmpltBtn'
                    ,case when T0.versionStatus = 010 then 'update_status_complete' else '' end as 'noclickCmpltBtn'
                    ,case when T0.versionStatus = 009 then '' else 'w3-disabled' end as 'disableChkBtn'
                    ,case when T0.versionStatus = 009 then 'update_status' else '' end as 'noclickChkBtn'
               FROM Versions T0 left outer join components_all T1 on T0.itemCode = T1.ca_versionCFG and T1.ca_itemGroup in (117,118)
               WHERE versionStatus in ('$status')
               and ItmsGrpCod in ('$itemGrp')
               order by thickness, T1.ca_itemCode asc, T0.despatchDate asc, SoDocNum
               LIMIT 45";

    $jobs_result = mysqli_query($db,$jobs_sql);
    $all_array = mysqli_fetch_all($jobs_result);

    echo json_encode($all_array);


?>
```

And this is what I have on the client side;

```
function get_jobs_to_bind(){
        console.log("Request data from server");
        $.post("/_api/jobs_to_bind_api.php",
        {
          status:'007',
          itemGrp:'121\',\'104\',\'106'          
        },

        function(data)          //on recieve of reply

      {
        console.log("Build table with data")
        $('#jobs_to_bind_table_body').empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
     var eachrow = "<tr>"
                 + "<td>" + item[0] + "</td>"
                 + "<td style='text-align:center'>" + item[1] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[2] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[3] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[4] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[7] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[8] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item[5] + "</td>"
                 + "<td><button class='w3-btn w3-round w3-green w3-tiny' value = '" + item[6] + "' onclick='update_status(\"008\","+ item[6] +")'>Gathered</button></td>"
                 + "<td><button id='viewgathererinfo' class='w3-btn w3-round w3-green w3-tiny' value = '" + item[6] + "' onclick='getgathererinfo("+ item[6] +")'>View</button></td>"
                 + "</tr>";
     $('#jobs_to_bind_table_body').append(eachrow);
    });
    filterbind2();
    filterbind3();
  },'json');

}
```

Comment: depends on your sql query too. post that as well

Comment: @Rahul Sorry I'm new to stack exchange and not sure how to add the code

Comment: edit your question and paste your code ... atleast that much

Comment: Thanks @Rahul I have added the code now

Answer (score 0):

What actually is happening is that we are getting a response but it is an empty response. The SQL is ok and runs in MySQL workbench. I have found the following function in php that will display any errors in the json_encode; `echo json_last_error_msg();` This shows the following error; "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"
This was a massive help! and explained why size wasn't effecting whether or not we got a result and why limiting the results did. There was obviously one row with a character that json_encode didn't like. I found the line in MySQL workbench and I think it was a colon causing the problem. Solved the issue by including a line in the serverside code to set the char set to utf8.

```
mysqli_set_charset($db,"UTF8");
```

Where $db is my database connection info